How to overlay two images?
So I am trying to have one image overlay another like the image. The screenshot image is how I wish the images to be placed. Screenshot of an image overlaying another
However whenever the screen change it size, the overlaying image doesn't move with it. It keeps its position on the screen no matter what I try or changes. I would like for it to have the same position on the background image.
I've tried changing the position for both background and overlay image, but it just made the image end up beside each other. Ive also tried changing width for both images and container + looking for others who had the same problem but just doesn't seem to work.


.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  /* Set to the size of your background image */
  height: auto;
}

.background-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Background image stays behind */
}

.overlay-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10rem;
  /* Adjust the position of the overlay image */
  left: 45rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Set size of the overlay image */
  z-index: 2;
  /* Overlay image appears on top */
}
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="background-img" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000">
    <img class="overlay-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
</section>




"However whenever the screen change it size, the overlaying image doesn't move with it. It keeps its position on the screen no matter what I try or changes. I would like for it to have the same position on the background image. Please can you explain this a bit more clearly? Thanks.

One thing confusing for me is that in your attached screenshot your background image is not really full height, right? In that case it should have had the full height and width of the img-container class.

I have submitted the answer, but the screenshot was a bit confusing for me. If it does not work, please provide more information for us to understand it better.

@mrconcerned So the screenshot  is more of what I wish it to look like.

@Rounin I can try. The overlay-img is at the correct position when the screen is about 1200px, but if the screen becomes smaller the img stays in the same position while the background-img moves/follows the screen size. Does that make sense?

@Anita I updated my answer with new snippet, I guess it should give the right result as in screenshot.

@Anita I'm still following the question, but did not hear from you yet.

sorry @mrconcerned ive been mia for some time and focused on studying instead. I ended up using grid instead, and it seems to work the best.

Instead of using top: 10rem; left: 45rem;, you can simply use bottom and right to place the image on the right bottom side of the background image.


.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
}

.background-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.overlay-img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="background-img" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000">
    <img class="overlay-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
</section>



and even you make the window smaller or larger then it moves according to that.
Update:
As you would like to place the overlay image on top of background image like in your screenshot, you can use similar method.


.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
}

.background-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.overlay-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="background-img" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000">
    <img class="overlay-img" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" alt="">
  </div>
</section>



